# Probability Problem about Pair of Shoes

Tags: probability

I've tried to solve this problem but I'm not sure about my answer.

Randomly draw $6$ shoes from $10$ pairs of shoes. What is the probability that exactly two pairs are observed?

My answer would be: $$\frac{\binom{10}2\binom{16}1\binom{14}1}{\binom{20}6}$$

But I was discussing with a friend and his answer was: $$\frac{\binom{10}2\binom82(2^2)}{\binom{20}6}$$ And this also seems correct to me.

Comment: $\binom{16}{1}\binom{14}{1}$ incorrectly applies some sort of significance to which of the unpaired shoes was the "first" of them to be picked as opposed to the "second" of them to be picked.  Your friend's answer was the correct one.

Comment: I don't quite understand lol

Comment: Let the pairs be labeled by uppercase letters and left-or-right by subscript $\ell$ and $r$ respectively.  Having picked $A_\ell A_r B_\ell B_r \color{red}{C_r} D_r$ is the same outcome as $A_\ell A_r B_\ell B_r \color{red}{D_r} C_r$.  You counted these as differently however.  You picked "which of the sixteen remaining shoes is listed in the fifth position.  Then, which of the 14 remaining shoes which don't pair with that is listed in the sixth position?"  It shouldn't have mattered whether it was $C_r$ or $D_r$ in the fifth position.  Reversing them is fine too.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First choose the two pairs that will match : you have to choose two pairs among $10$, which gives you ${10 \choose 2}$ possible choices.

Then you have to choose the two others shoes. For the first one, you have $16$ possibilities (there are $16$ shoes left) ; for the second one, only $14$ (because the second shoe must not belong to the same pair as the first one). But the order between these two shoes does not count, so you have to divide the result by $2$. You have here $16 \times 14 / 2$ possible choices.

So the total number of choices is ${10 \choose 2} \times 16 \times 7$, so the final probability is $$\frac{{10 \choose 2} \times 16 \times 7}{{20 \choose 6}} \simeq 0.13$$

Comment: I don't get why you divide with 2

Comment: Because choosing shoe number $17$ then shoe number $8$ is considered as the same as choosing shoe number $8$ then shoe number $17$. Therefore at this step, you have counted each possibility twice.